# How to compare variable amount of days using UNIX timestamp (stored as int) 

Tags: mysql, unix-timestamp

I need to pull a variable amount of days of data from a MySQL database that stores the date as a UNIX timestamp in an int column.

For example, if I need the last 5 days of data, what would my query be?
(All queries would start from current date and would go back x amount of days).

Comment: Under what OS/language/framework? (And is this homework?)

Comment: It is not hw, it's mysql as noted by the tag.

Comment: There is no unix timestamp data type in mysql. Are you sure you are not referring to timestamp?

Comment: @ajreal: I know there's no unix timestamp natively, but that is the way it is being stored (in an int column).

Comment: Mind to update your question to be **clearer**?

Comment: I was assuming that you were accessing the DB in a framework in another language, not directly over the console; sorry. According to the MySQL docs, something like `WHERE UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-86400*5 <= foo` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timestamp is considered one of the [Date and Time types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-types.html) and therefore any of the [Date Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) can be used on it.

```
SELECT * FROM your_table
WHERE Ftimestamp_column > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 DAY));
```

Comment: Does it matter if the timestamp_column is being stored as an int? The query doesn't seem to be working for me.

Comment: Also, it is a UNIX timestamp, not a native MySQL timestamp.

Comment: `... > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(...))` will fix it up.

Comment: Sorry, I read that to be literal *timestamp*. **Marc B** has the answer. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @kylex If you column is indexed, Marc suggestion is better, and it allowed mysql make use on index

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried it but there's a MySQL function to convert unix timestamps into MySQL dates and then you can use DATE_SUB() or whatever. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime